# mongodb filter and project only documents that have biggest id for the provided pattern

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Lets say we have following documents:

```
{
 reportName: 'ABC_REPORT'
 reports: [
 {
  "startDate" : ISODate("2017-07-02T00:00:00Z"),
  "endDate" : ISODate("2017-07-08T00:00:00Z"),
  "data" : [ { DATA_ID: '0123404' }, { DATA_ID: '111101' }, { DATA_ID: '22201' } ] 
},
{
 "startDate" : ISODate("2017-07-09T00:00:00Z"),
 "endDate" : ISODate("2017-07-15T00:00:00Z"),
 "data" : [ { DATA_ID: '111103' } ] },
{
 "startDate" : ISODate("2017-07-16T00:00:00Z"),
 "endDate" : ISODate("2017-07-22T00:00:00Z"),
 "data" : [{ DATA_ID: '0123403' }, { DATA_ID: '111109' }]
 },
{
 "startDate" : ISODate("2017-07-16T00:00:00Z"),
 "endDate" : ISODate("2017-07-22T00:00:00Z"),
 "data" : [{ DATA_ID: '0123402' }]
 }
]}
```

Now I want to write a query that should search for the DATA_IDs that starts with ('01234', '1111', '222'). And if for each pattern it returns more than one DATA_ID then the result should only have the biggest one only.
Only last two digits of the same pattern are going to be increment.

Expect to get an array like :

```
{
data: [{ DATA_ID: '111109' },
       { DATA_ID: '0123404' },
       { DATA_ID: '22201' }
      ]
 }
```

Iam trying to solve this with aggregation-framework but really struggling with it.

Comment: "By biggest" , do you mean  length or weight ?

Comment: between 'abc101', 'abc102', 'abc103'. 'abc103' is the biggest. let me edit the strings in the question so it will make more sense.

Comment: I have added a answer too. pls check second part of it

Answer (score 0):

If you need biggest by length

```
db.col.aggregate([
{
 $unwind:"$reports"
},
{
 $unwind:"$reports.data"
},
{
 $replaceRoot:{ newRoot:"$reports.data"}
},
{
 $project:{
  "DATA_ID":1,
  "GRP_ID":{
    $switch: {
   branches: [
      { case: {$eq:[{ $indexOfBytes:["$DATA_ID","01234"]},0]}, then: "0124" },
      {  case: {$eq:[{ $indexOfBytes:["$DATA_ID","xyz"]},0]}, then: "xyz" },
      {  case: {$eq:[{ $indexOfBytes:["$DATA_ID","abcd"]},0]}, then: "abcd" }
   ],
   default: ""
}
  }
 }
},
{
 $group:{
  _id:"$GRP_ID",
  DATA_IDS:{$addToSet:"$DATA_ID"}
 }
},
{
 $project:{
   _id:0,
  DATA_ID:{
   $reduce:{
     input:"$DATA_IDS",
     initialValue:"",
     in:{$cond:[{$gte:[{$strLenCP:"$$this"},{$strLenCP:"$$value"}]},"$$this","$$value"]}
   }
  }
 }
}

])
```

if you need biggest by weight

```
db.col.aggregate([
{
 $unwind:"$reports"
},
{
 $unwind:"$reports.data"
},
{
 $replaceRoot:{ newRoot:"$reports.data"}
},
{
 $project:{
  "DATA_ID":1,
  "GRP_ID":{
    $switch: {
   branches: [
      { case: {$eq:[{ $indexOfBytes:["$DATA_ID","01234"]},0]}, then: "0124" },
      {  case: {$eq:[{ $indexOfBytes:["$DATA_ID","xyz"]},0]}, then: "xyz" },
      {  case: {$eq:[{ $indexOfBytes:["$DATA_ID","abcd"]},0]}, then: "abcd" }
   ],
   default: ""
}
  }
 }
},
{
 $group:{
  _id:"$GRP_ID",
  DATA_IDS:{$addToSet:"$DATA_ID"}
 }
},
{
 $project:{
   _id:0,
  DATA_ID:{
   $reduce:{
     input:"$DATA_IDS",
     initialValue:"",
     in:{$cond:[{$gte:["$$this","$$value"]},"$$this","$$value"]}
   }
  }
 }
}

])
```